# bootstrap css active tab inherit styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am building a tab system and with for each tab to have some style applied once active using the `.acive` class, I can do this like so

```
.side-nav-cat li:nth-child(2).active:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border: 25px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    border-left: 25px solid #628179;
}
```

how ever I do not with to repeat all the same code on every `nth-child`

so I tried the following code so I only have to include   `border-left: 25px solid color;` for each individual `nth-child`, I cant seem to get the `nth-child` to inherit all the styles from `.side-nav-cat li:after .active`

any idea why and how to fix it ?
thanks.

```
.side-nav-cat li:after .active {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border: 25px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    border-left: 25px solid #628179;
}

.side-nav-cat li:nth-child(2).active:after {
    border-left: 25px solid red;
}

.side-nav-cat li:nth-child(2).active:after {
    border-left: 25px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: `.side-nav-cat li.active:after`, not `.side-nav-cat li:after .active`.

Comment: thanks, for the help +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first selector is looking for an element inside your `<li>` with the class of `.active`; rather than looking for an `<li>` with the class of `.active`.

The below should work;

```
.side-nav-cat li.active:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border: 25px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
    border-left: 25px solid #628179;
}

.side-nav-cat li:nth-child(2).active:after {
    border-left: 25px solid red;
}

.side-nav-cat li:nth-child(2).active:after {
    border-left: 25px solid blue;
}
```